# How to avoid redundant code while using setter methods

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've an instance and I needs to update the fields and pass the instance to another method.

I've to update more than 10 fields (using mutator/setter methods) of the instance.

In that case every field update, I use instancevariable.setXXXX() way...

Is there any better approach avoid redundancy like every time I've to use instancevariable.setXXX ? I'm not the owner of the class, My method is similar like

```
 public AClass method1(AClass instance) {
    instance.setField1(value);
    instance.setField2(value);
    .
    .
    .
    instance.setField10(value);
    return instance;
    }
```

Comment: builder pattern?

Comment: Do you provide same value (`value`) to all setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not owner of class `AClass` it's better to extract all logic for setting parameters in separate class. Below is a couple of examples depending of where do you get parameters `value`:

**Values are diffirent each time**

```
public static class AClassInitializer {
    private final AClass pattern;
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    private AClassInitializer(AClass pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public AClassInitializer field1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        return this;
    }

    public AClassInitializer field2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
        return this;
    }

    public AClass init() {
        pattern.setField1(value1);
        pattern.setField2(value2);
        return pattern;
    }
}

public AClass method1(AClass instance) {
    return new AClassInitializer(instance).field1(value1).field2(value2).init();
}
```

**Values are the same each time**

```
public static class AClassInitializer {
    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;

    public AClassInitializer(String value1, String value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public AClass init(AClass pattern) {
        pattern.setField1(value1);
        pattern.setField2(value2);
        return pattern;
    }
}

AClassInitializer aClassInitializer = new AClassInitializer(value1, value2);

public AClass method1(AClass instance) {
    return aClassInitializer.init(instance);
}
```